# maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to do a rest web service example.

This is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>restService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>restService</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

When I run:

```
>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building restService 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ restService ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Documents\Universita\tesi\javaWorkspace\restService\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Documents\Universita\tesi\javaWorkspace\restService\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ restService ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.935 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-29T17:05:52+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/185M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project restService: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12: Failure to find org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9 in http://localhost:8081/artifactory/remote-repos was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of remote-repos has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

The problem seem to be artifactory that not resolve the dependencies.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Show us your settings.xml or however you configured artifactory. Looks like you can't get things from Maven central.

Comment: solved with mvn -U package...thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Solved with `mvn -U package`
With it artifactory was forced to download the artifacts